# Dynamic Dependent Select from dropdown using Jquery and Ajax and json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dropdown

I'm looking for some help with the code below,

I have this form that each dropdown list depends on the one above it, so you based on what your selection is, the right data will show on the next selection. I want dropdown list 4 (select house) activate based on dropdown list 1 select country. so when the country selected. both state(2) and the house(4) will be activated and showing data. see screenshot below,

[image]

here is the HTML code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

load_json_data('country');

function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
{
 var html_code = '';
 $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahammoudi/jason_data/master/data.jason', function(data){

  html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
   if(id == 'country')
   {
    if(value.parent_id == '0')
    {
     html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
    }
   }
   else
   {
    if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
    {
     html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
    }
   }
  });
  $('#'+id).html(html_code);
 });

}

$(document).on('change', '#country', function(){
 var country_id = $(this).val();
 if(country_id != '')
 {
  load_json_data('state', country_id);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#state').html('<option value="">Select state</option>');
  $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
  $('#house').html('<option value="">Select house</option>');
 }
});
$(document).on('change', '#state', function(){
 var state_id = $(this).val();
 if(state_id != '')
 {
  load_json_data('city', state_id);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
 }
});

$(document).on('change', '#city', function(){
 var city_id = $(this).val();
 if(city_id != '')
 {
  load_json_data('house', city_id);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#house').html('<option value="">Select house</option>');
 }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | JSON - Dynamic Dependent Dropdown List using Jquery and Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">JSON - Dynamic Dependent Dropdown List using Jquery and Ajax</h2><br /><br />
   <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select state</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="house" id="house" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select house</option>
   <br />
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just in case someone want to take a look into the json data file, its here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahammoudi/jason_data/master/data.jason

Comment: What the problem is your question?

Comment: droplist number 4 (select house) need to be active when droplist number 1 (Country) selected. currently number 4 will be activated when drop list number 3 (selecte city) selected. if you run the code snippet you will get what i'm talking about.

Comment: Ok, as per my understanding if you select the first drop-down 4 dropdowns fill it's correct to let me know so I'm preparing demo?

Comment: currently each drop down depents on the one above it, for example, drop down number 2, wont be available until you select something from dropdown number 1. and drop down number 3 depends on number two. what i want is, i want dropdown number 4 become active and ready to select something when drop down number 1 selected not dropdown number 3, if i change this line $(document).on('change', '#city', function() to something like this $(document).on('change', '#country', function(), the drobdown will work, but with the incorrect list, since we have variable "city_id" set to (this)

Comment: ++ so the variable need to be changed from (this) to the correct lists value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has been fixed. here is what i did>

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

load_json_data('country');

function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
{
 var html_code = '';
 $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ahammoudi/jason_data/master/data.jason', function(data){

  html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
  $.each(data, function(key, value){
   if(id == 'country')
   {
    if(value.parent_id == '0')
    {
     html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
    }
   }
   else
   {
    if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
    {
     html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
    }
   }
  });
  $('#'+id).html(html_code);
 });

}

$(document).on('change', '#country', function(){
 var country_id = $(this).val();
 if(country_id != '')
 {
  load_json_data('state', country_id);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#state').html('<option value="">Select state</option>');
  $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
  $('#house').html('<option value="">Select house</option>');
 }
});
$(document).on('change', '#state', function(){
 var state_id = $(this).val();
 if(state_id != '')
 {
  load_json_data('city', state_id);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
 }
});

$(document).on('change', '#country', function(){
 var country_id = $(this).val();
 if(country_id == 1)
 {
  load_json_data('house', 7);
 }
 else if(country_id == 2)
 {
  load_json_data('house', 8);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#house').html('<option value="">Select house</option>');
 }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorialx</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">JSON x</h2><br /><br />
   <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select state</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="house" id="house" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select house</option>
   <br />
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

i just changed the last function to

```
$(document).on('change', '#country', function(){
 var country_id = $(this).val();
 if(country_id == 1)
 {
  load_json_data('house', 7);
 }
 else if(country_id == 2)
 {
  load_json_data('house', 8);
 }
 else
 {
  $('#house').html('<option value="">Select house</option>');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependent Dropdown edit

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('table').on('click','#edit',function(){
var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");
alert(id);

if(confirm('Are you sure to edit this record ?'))
{ 
    $.ajax({
       url: 'edit.php',
       type: 'GET',
       data: {id: id},
       error: function() {
          alert('Something is wrong');
       },
       success: function(response) {
         $('#submit').hide();
         $('#update').css('display','block');
         
        var data=JSON.parse(response);
        for(i in data){
          alert(data[i].id);
           $('#id').val(data[i].id);
           $('#name').val(data[i].name);
           $('#age').val(data[i].age);
           $('#phone').val(data[i].phone);
           $('#email').val(data[i].email);
           $('#state').val(data[i].state);
           $.ajax({
          url:'drop.php',
          type:'post',
          data:{s_id:data[i].state},
          success:function(res){
            $('#district').html(res);
        
           $('#district').val(data[i].district);
           $('#address').val(data[i].address);
           $('#gender').val(data[i].gender);

          }
         })
        }
        
    }
    });

    }

   })
   })
   </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).